# MIT Scheme using special characters in the interpreter

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, scheme, lisp, mit-scheme

I am using MIT scheme, and would like to be able to do something like this:

`(define π 3.14159265)`

Without having an encoding error like this:

```
;Illegal character: #\U+80
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1
```

MIT Scheme [does have Unicode support](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Unicode.html), but it appears that it doesn't have support for unicode *in the code*, which is what I am looking to do. It turns out that ISO-8859-1 (the encoding used in MIT Scheme) does not have any greek letters within it, which is a pity.

Solutions that might work, but are not very good:

1. Writing all of my code into text files and using the built in unicode support to `read` in the unicode characters as code.
2. Rewriting the entire interpreter to accept unicode names
3. Using a different lisp implementation which allows for Unicode names.

Can't wait to hear from the Stack Overflowers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use unicode symbols in guile, gambit, scm, and chicken for sure.

Comment: And in Racket (tested the languages `#!racket`, `#!r5rs`, and `#!r6rs`)

Comment: I probably shouldn't be using MIT-Scheme for non-academic purposes anyway.